# Camunda: How pass variable from parent process to subprocess. (which is started by event)

Tags: java, bpmn, camunda

I have a process which creates a sub-process by event. I would like to pass a variable from the parent process to the sub-process. One way which I found is by using:

```
MessageCorrelationResult result = runtimeService
    .createMessageCorrelation("newEvent")
    .setVariable(TOUR_ID, id)    //trigger instance where customer matches
    .correlateWithResult();
runtimeService.setVariable(result.getProcessInstance().getId(),"variableToSend", "val");
```

But, `result.getProcessInstance()` returns null and it seems that this is a known issue: 
https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-7772

Do you know how can I pass variables from parent to sub process using other approach  ?

[image]

Comment: Which camunda version are you using? IIrc setting variables via message correlation should be supported with 7.9

Comment: 7.8.1, do you mean that https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-7772 bug fixed in 7.9 ?

Comment: @JanGalinski I have tested with 7.9, seams same bug exist in 7.9

Answer (score 6):

If you call a subprocess a Call Activity task, you can set up a variable mapping.

In Mapping -> all

Out Mapping -> all

In this case, all the variables available in the execution of your parent process shall be available at the sub-process.

[image]

Comment: That is the way make in in GUI. The other way would be also possible to writen in XML shema code like:
<camunda:in variables="all" />
<camunda:out variables="all" />

under section 
<bpmn:extensionElements>

Comment: Instead of changing all bpmn schema XML files, would it be possible to have some method in just one class which handles all possible variables for all possible parent and sub processes. Like some listener or something in that way?